# LIME Random Forest explanations:

Tags: random-forest, explainable-ai

I'm using [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) to explain my random forest model. Everything is working great. However, I don't quite understand the image that is generated. Taking the example from the Readme:

[image]

How can it predict poisonous with 1.00 but still have a gill-size=broad which has 0.13 probability? Or do I misunderstand the table?

I already asked this question in [the github project](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/issues/421), but didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer mostly lies in the fact that these are just approximations and they're not super exact because of the small data set and nature of decision trees. The prediction was really 1.0 (I'm guessing all trees' leaves agreed entirely on the prediction).

If gill_size != broad, it would still be 1.0, you could say (1.13 is meaningless). But maybe if gill_size != broad and odor != foul you could expect the probability to be about 1.0 + 0.13 - 0.26 = 0.87.

A little more explanation is at https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20continuous%20and%20categorical%20features.html

Comment: Hi @Sean Owen - I have a similar question. Do you know when the predicted class is positive (orange) but most of the features have `negative feature importance value.` How should we interpret that? Is the prediction becoming positive because of the intercept (as most of the features are all pointing towards negative class (blue color)). If you have time, can help me with this post? I have put a bounty on it. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/107928/usefulness-of-intercept-in-layman-terms-eli5